# How to add a image in Pivot header similar to page controller of iOS in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

I am currently working with Windows 10 and Pivot control. I am aware that we can customize the header template by adding an Image or customizing the TextBlock. I know how  to customize basic template like following

```
<Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                       FontSize="22"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```

This works perfectly fine for basic purpose but I want to achieve an output similar to the following screenshot. Add ellipse for each header and it should at the center of the page.

[image]

Can someone suggest whether this is possible or not?

**Update**

I added a StackPanel like below.

```
 <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Ellipse Fill="Cyan"
                             Height="10"
                             Width="10"
                             Margin="10,0"/>
                    <Ellipse Fill="Gainsboro"
                             Height="10"
                             Width="10"
                             Margin="10,0"/>
                    <Ellipse Fill="Gainsboro"
                             Height="10"
                             Width="10"
                             Margin="10,0"/>

                </StackPanel>
```

Now how to assign *PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush* and *PivotHeaderForegroundUnselectedBrush* to ellipses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For designing ellipses on center of page.

**Option 1**
You can accomplish is by having binding a margin property. This margin property will need to be updated for each resize.

**Option2**
Else specify a Stackpanel with Orientation as Horizontal, Center aligned and containing ellipses which are updated as soon as Pivot selection changes. You can find a similar control being created by [Jerry Nixon Pagination](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/04/lets-code-build-your-own-flipview-page.html)

As for Ellipses Color change you can Create a template for different state, use a trigger or even override current Pivot header templates

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush" Color="Blue" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PivotHeaderForegroundUnselectedBrush" Color="White" />
```

Comment: Updated my question.Please suggest. Also, how to remove Pivot header from the Pivot. I tried adding blank DataTemplate to Header Template but still space is occupied by the header.

Comment: If you are using stackpanel you would also need to raiseproperty changed events for changing the stackpanel output as per page change refer jerry's tutorial above it will show you how to bind and change colors based on your requirement. The resources need to be assigned in App.xaml as resource.

Comment: If you are not using MVVM you can still grasp an idea from the tutorial For every selection changed you can get which item is selected and update that ellipse color. and for ellipse tap just change the pivot item.

Comment: ok I will try. Is it possible for you to edit my code and create a sample?

Comment: Making a sample would take some time. Why not you try to create yourself if you face a problem feel free to post the problem on stackoverflow.